# Pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays

```
int (*n)[3];         
n=&m[i];
```

Where `m` is a 2 dimensional array.which has **3** columns.  Can someone please tell me why it is necessary to use the **&** sign.  I mean m[0] will give the address of the 0th array and m[1] will give the address of first array.  Why we need that & sign then?  It is showing assignment from an invalid pointer type.

I am new to c programming, so please help.

Comment: You also could use: `n = (m + i);`

Answer (score 2):

The `&` character is the *address-of* operator, it returns a pointer to the value in the expression, in your case it returns a pointer to the array in `m[i]`.

You need to use it because otherwise if you use just plain `m[i]` the array decays to a pointer to the first element, which is of type `int *`.